# Conditional Boolean Loc Indexing VS ISIN Indexing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I get the same indexing results using these two methods:

```
data.loc[data['loan_status']== 'Default'].head()

data[data['loan_status'].isin(['Default'])].head()
```

Is there an advantage of one over the other?

Also is there a reason why isin needs a ([]) parameter to work whereas most methods simply need a ()?

Answer (score 0):

`.isin` allows you to supply a list of values to check. For instance, if you were looking for `'Default'` or `Defaulted`, or something like that, you could say:

```
data[data['loan_status'].isin(['Default', 'Defaulted'])].head()
```

Whereas otherwise, you would have to give it multiple conditions, like:

```
data.loc[(data['loan_status'] == 'Default') | (data['loan_status'] == 'Defaulted')]
```

Comment: To summarise, for a single value use `==` or `pd.Series.eq`, multiple values use `pd.Series.isin`.